# Round down/truncate decimal places within column

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

There seems to be a number of neat and simple methods for rounding all numbers in a column to 1 decimal place, using awk's printf or even bash's printf. However I can't find an equally simple method for just reducing all numbers in a column to 1 decimal place (but not round up). The simplest method for sorting this at the moment would be to round to 2 decimal places and then remove the last character from every line in column 1. Anyone got a better method for this? An example input and output would be as follows:

Input

```
123.434    
1456.8123  
2536.577    
345.95553  
23643.1454
```

Output

```
123.4    
1456.8  
2536.5    
345.9  
23643.1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

easy enough with `grep`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
123.434
1456.8123
2536.577
345.95553
23643.1454    

$ grep -o '^[0-9]*\.[0-9]' ip.txt 
123.4
1456.8
2536.5
345.9
23643.1
```

- `^` start of line
- `[0-9]*` zero or more digits
- `\.` match literal dot character
- `[0-9]` match a digit
- since `-o` option of `grep` is used, only matched portion is printed, effectively removing remaining characters

If there are other columns, use `sed`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
123.434 a
1456.8123 b
2536.577 c
345.95553 d
23643.1454 e

$ sed -E 's/^([0-9]*\.[0-9])[0-9]*/\1/' ip.txt
123.4 a
1456.8 b
2536.5 c
345.9 d
23643.1 e
```

- `-E` use extended regex
- required pattern is captured in `()` and `\1` used in replacement section
- `[0-9]*` after the capture group gets deleted

Further reading:

- [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: I never knew you could do this with grep!  Fantastic